# Access a variable value having it's reference address as string

Tags: c++

I want to convert a pointer value to string, so I have a variable address as string, and then using this string to convert back to a pointer value, and be able to access the original variable value.

```
#include <sstream> 
#include <string>  

int *a = new int[5];
 a[0] = 105;
 a[1] = 106;
 a[2] = 107;
 a[3] = 108;
 a[4] = 109;

 const void * address = static_cast<const void*>(a);
 std::stringstream ss;
 ss << address;
 std::string var_address = ss.str();
```

Now I want to do something like this:

```
int *z = var_address;

cout << z[0]; // gives 105
cout << z[1]; // gives 106
```

How I can do this ?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. What do you need this for?

Comment: There is no standard way to read a pointer value, and the standard method to write a pointer value is implementation defined. So a better way would be to convert the pointer into an integer, and then write the integer, and do the reverse when you want the pointer back. The type `uintptr_t` is an unsigned integer which is guaranteed to be large enough to hold any pointer.

Comment: I want to learn

Comment: @AyayMatty OK, so let's say you have the adress of a variable stored as string, just convert it back to an integer value and assign it to the pointer using a cast.

Comment: I don't know what you're asking; the terms are too vague. What are you actually trying to do? And what for?

Comment: What ***exactly*** are you trying to learn? Because in all my years of working with C++ I have never had any reason, whatsoever, to learn anything like that. And I was still able to accomplish everything I needed to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `uintptr_t` to hold your pointer value. The type `uintptr_t` is an unsigned integer which is guaranteed to be large enough to hold any pointer. Like this

```
int *a = new int[5];
a[0] = 105;
a[1] = 106;
a[2] = 107;
a[3] = 108;
a[4] = 109;

const void * address = static_cast<const void*>(a);
std::stringstream ss;
ss << reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(address); // write an integer
std::string var_address = ss.str();

std::stringstream ss2(var_address);
uintptr_t temp;
ss2 >> temp;                                // read back the integer
int *z = reinterpret_cast<int*>(temp);      // convert integer to a pointer

cout << z[0]; // gives 105
cout << z[1]; // gives 106
```